# Combined queries returns different results

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The results of a query I created from two different queries is not returning the same results.

Query A

```
SELECT 
c.fullname Course,
u.firstname First,
u.lastname Last,
u.id ID,
u.institution Company

FROM (mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS st)
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON st.userid=u.id
JOIN mdl_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id=sc.course
Join mdl_user_enrolments AS uenr ON uenr.userid=u.id
Join mdl_enrol AS enr ON enr.id=uenr.enrolid 

WHERE (
(st.value='incomplete' OR st.value='not attempted') 
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(uenr.timecreated)>60)
ORDER BY c.fullname, u.lastname,u.firstname, u.id
```

Query B

```
SELECT
c.fullname AS Course,
u.firstname AS Firstname,
u.lastname AS Lastname,
u.id AS ID,
u.institution AS Company,

IF (u.lastaccess = 0,'never',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess),'%Y-%m-%d')) AS dLastAccess

,(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeaccess),'%Y-%m-%d') FROM mdl_user_lastaccess WHERE userid=u.id AND courseid=c.id) AS CourseLastAccess 
FROM mdl_user_enrolments AS ue
JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ue.userid
LEFT JOIN mdl_user_lastaccess AS ul ON ul.userid = u.id
WHERE ul.timeaccess IS NULL AND (DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated))>60)
ORDER BY u.id, c.fullname
```

I have combined them into Query C

```
SELECT
c.fullname AS Course,
u.firstname AS Firstname,
u.lastname AS Lastname,
u.id AS IDNumber,
u.institution AS Institution,

IF (u.lastaccess = 0,'never',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess),'%Y-%m-%d')) AS dLastAccess

,(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeaccess),'%Y-%m-%d') FROM mdl_user_lastaccess WHERE userid=u.id AND courseid=c.id) AS CourseLastAccess


FROM mdl_user_enrolments AS ue
JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ue.userid
LEFT JOIN mdl_user_lastaccess AS ul ON ul.userid = u.id
WHERE (ul.timeaccess IS NULL OR ue.userid IN
(SELECT u.id 
FROM (mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS st)
JOIN mdl_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid

WHERE c.id=sc.course AND st.userid=u.id AND (st.value='incomplete' OR st.value='not attempted') 
 )
)AND (DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated))>60)
ORDER BY c.fullname, u.lastname,u.firstname
```

I have not found where my logic is incorrect in Query C.  Query C is adding an incorrect record not found by either A or B and duplicating entries in a couple of cases.

I would like some pointers on where my logic on combining the 2 went astray.

I fixed the commas in this post, the actual queries did have them.

My intent is to list all users that have been enrolled into a course but within a given timeframe, have not logged into the system, accessed the course and finally have not completed the activity in the course.

So the logic I am looking for is:
If the user has not logged in within 60 days - display name
If logged in but has not accessed the course within 60 days - display name
If logged in and has accessed the course but has not completed the course activity- display name

Query A does list all users that started the activity but have not completed within 60 days
Query B does list all users that have not logged in or accessed the course within 60 days

In trying to combine the 2 queries to satisfy all 3 conditions is where I am having problems.  I first tried a UNION but could not get it to work.

Comment: You missed commas in second line of query A and sixth line of query B.

Comment: @Rachcha - Thank you for pointing out the missing commas.  I have corrected the post, however the actual queries were correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting from the same worlds in both queries.  Query A has 6 tables it is selecting from and Query B has 5 (its missing the mdl_scorm table) and your Query C has the 5 tables that Query B has.  So now your scope for Query A has changed.  That extra table could have been eliminating rows in the join that are now appearing in Query C for the selects of A.

I would check Query A with the mdl_scorm table missing from the query and you probably have a different result size.

Think of it as

select COLUMNS from TABLES where FILTERS;  TABLES (universe of data) needs to be the same for both queries for you to just join the COLUMNS and FILTERS (expand selection and limit results)

Comment: The missing table is on purpose.  Query A is checking if a course has not been completed within the time frame given based on when the individual was enrolled in the course.  Query B is checking if an enrolled user ever logged into the system or accessed the course.